# Symlink dotfiles to Documents/Dotfiles

Tags: symlink

I have a setup script which creates links between my dotfiles repo and the files at the root of my Home directory. Generally speaking, the process looks like this for each file:

```
ln -s ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
```

Is this linked in the correct direction? E.g, I want to be able to keep my customizations in `Documents` and just point to them. Most of the documentation I've read seems to assume a traditional Unix or Linux environment, so I'm not sure this is correct.

The relevant part of my setup script is below

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function makeLinks() {
  ln -s ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_aliases ~/.bash_aliases
  ln -s ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
  ln -s ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_prompt ~/.bash_prompt
  ln -s ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig
  ln -s ~/Documents/Dotfiles/.gitignore_global ~/.gitignore_global

  read -rp "This may overwrite existing files. Are you sure? (y/n) " -n 1;
  echo "";
  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    makeLinks
  fi;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man ln` clearly says:

```
ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
```

So yeah, your command seems reasonable.

The script, however, is odd. `makeLinks` is never invoked and the prompt asking for confirmation would just cause recursion. You probably meant to place it outside the function definition.

Comment: Sigh, should have seen that. I've updated it and now get prompted whether or not to actually create the links, which is what I tried to do (poorly) :)